# Connection test using fabric8 api

Tags: java, fabric8

Is there a way to do connection test prior to doing any operation over the clusters using fabric8 api?

The workaround that i am using now is to list the pods available using client.pods api call.

Comment: Umm, KubernetesClient usually throws KubernetesClientException in case it's unable to reach Kubernetes APIServer. Could you please elaborate your question? Or pehaps you want to check health of apiServer?

Comment: You are right @RohanKumar right now i am checking the connection by attempting an empty get pods operation. 

I am getting the inputs like cluster masterurl and the authtoken as user input. I am trying to validate it before persisting them.

Comment: I think it would be nice of Fabric8 Kubenetes Client threw some special exception on not being able to reach Kubernetes Cluster(`KubernetesNotFoundException`). Right now I need to extract cause from KubernetesClientException in order to check if it failed to connect: https://gist.github.com/rohanKanojia/742c8b7ce67dea45162d8f2e12421ef7

Comment: Maybe we should create an issue about it on Fabric8 Github repository...